# Bound mismatch in espresso tests' ActivityTestRule

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-studio-2.2, android-espresso

When I try to run espresso tests in Android Studio 2.2.2 I'm getting the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type MainActivity is not a valid substitute for
>   the bounded parameter  of the type
>   ActivityTestRule

MainActivity is an extension of Activity.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule
        = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```

What can be causing it?

Comment: This part of your code looks fine. Check again if MainActivity extends Activity (android.app.Activity) and if ActivityTestRule is imported from android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule. If they are, try to do clean build and run again...

Comment: I double checked and everything was as it supposed to be. I left it for some time and somehow it works now, but I don't know what had fixed the issue as I made a lot of changes to the code in the meantime. I'll leave the question open. Maybe someone also had this kind of an issue and knows what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had your Activity test class named the same as the Activity and it was referencing itself

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33377042)